# How to set the "enable_iam_login" parameter in DBeaver database connection for GCP Postgresql database?

Tags: postgresql, dbeaver, google-cloud-iam

I'm using a GCP Postgresql database with internal IP and I need to use my GCP IAM account.
As there is no public IP, I can't use the cloud_sql_proxy and set the "enable_iam_login" parameter in the connection.
Therefore, I need to configure it somehow in the Postgresql database connection inside DBeaver.
Do you have any idea of how should I configure this parameter in the configuration?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This page lists the plans supporting AWS credentials
https://dbeaver.com/docs/dbeaver/AWS-Credentials/
*"This feature is available in Lite, Enterprise, Ultimate and Team editions only."*
i.e. DBeaver Community does apparently not support it.